# cassandra skip columns on copy data from csv file

Tags: cassandra

I want to copy some columns from csv file to cassandra table. There's 300 columns in csv file and I only need the first ten columns. There's no header in the csv file.
I tried

```
copy table from 'file.csv' with header=false and skipcols=[range(11,300)]
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: “it didn’t work” - what happened? Did you get an error message? Did it do the import but not as you expected? What version are you using? The docs (https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshCopyFrom.html) don’t make any mention of using `range` in the skipcols option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you specify column names after table name i.e.

```
COPY TABLE xx(c1,c2..C30) FROM ..
```